# Aligning the bottom of an inline block with the bottom of text (excluding descenders)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

How can I align the bottom of an inline block (call it 'IB') with the bottom of the text - excluding descenders like that on 'g' - in a parent element (call it 'PE')? This should be in a way which generalises whatever the size of the text - I don't want to hardcode size-specific pixel values.

Here is an example of the HTML I'd use, with the classes I'd need CSS for:

```
<div class="pe">
    Parent text line
    <span class="ib" style="display: inline-block;">
        - and child text line
    </span>
</div>
```

And here's what I'd like it to look like:

[image: http://imgur.com/S1l7Y]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP updated saying: "Thanks, but I've edited the question to clarify I don't want to hardcode size-specific pixel values."

In that case, I'm afraid there isn't a solution that will automatically fix different lines with different text sizes. The other solution I provided isn't even perfect across all of the browsers with some combinations of font sizes, because Chrome/Opera round inexact values differently than Firefox/IE, so even with my solution, you'd need to use some browser-specific css. The only thing similar to an universal solution would be setting vertical-align: middle; but I wouldn't trust that to work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below css to ib. And change the bottom margin to control alignment.

```
.ib{
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 10px; 
     vertical-align: bottom;
     margin:0 0 1px 0;
}​
```

@Rorok_89 I know i am adding one more line of css but its justa way to do it in a different way. Your answer is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, but I've edited the question to clarify I don't want to hardcode size-specific pixel values.

Comment: @SVS, if my answer is perfect I could use a +1 :3

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Rorok_89/Z8TWH/

```
.ib{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 10px; 
 vertical-align: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've edited the question to clarify I don't want to hardcode size-specific pixel values. (PS: it looks like I'd actually need a different vertical-align as at http://jsfiddle.net/tog22/Mp4fB/ )

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid there isn't a solution that will automatically fix different lines with different text sizes. The solution I provided isn't even perfect across all of the browsers with some combinations of font sizes, because Chrome/Opera round inexact values differently than Firefox/IE, so even with my solution, you'd need to use some browser-specific css. The only thing similar to an universal solution would be setting `vertical-align: middle;` but I wouldn't trust that to work consistently.

Comment: New answer posted, then. Cheers!